# What are the use cases for render (:update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

With Rails controllers, what exactly is `render (:update)` for?

Is is specifically for defining RJS inline or does it have more uses than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally thats what its for. You would tend to use it when a method is called using ajax ans you want to update something on the page to let the client know something has happened.